# Italicising "et al." in references when using Harvard package / citation style

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

I'm relatively new to latex and this is my first post here, and I've tried to include a minimum working example below but I'm not sure if i've done it right. My main question is regarding the use of the [harvard package](https://ctan.org/pkg/harvard?lang=en) for citations.

I would like to know how to change all "et al."  text that comes up with more than 3 authors for a reference to italicized font. I've read online that this actually isn't a requirement of the actual Harvard citation style, but this modification is what my university requires.

In other words, instead of  Fitzherbert et al., 2008, I would like it to be reflected as  Fitzherbert *et al.*, 2008.

This is my code and document so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[dcucite,abbr]{harvard}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}

\chapter{introduction}
Vegetable oils are one of the most rapidly expanding sectors of agricultural expansion \cite{oil-biodiv}. 

\bibliographystyle{dcu}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}References}
 \newpage\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And in my references.bib document, I have an entry set out like this:

```
@article{oil-biodiv,  
title={How will oil palm expansion affect biodiversity?},  
author={Fitzherbert, Emily B and Struebig, Matthew J and Morel, Alexandra and Danielsen, Finn and Br{\"u}hl, Carsten A and Donald, Paul F and Phalan, Ben},  
journal={Trends in ecology \& evolution},  
volume={23},  
number={10},  
pages={538--545},  
year={2008},  
publisher={Elsevier} 
}
```

Thank you and will really appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: The order in your code example looks slightly off: You can't have `\usepackage` before `\documentclass`. But things should work if you move the `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}` line to the top.

Comment: @moewe oh sorry, my bad - will edit it here! i think thats just a problem with my minimum working example, because i actually have my packages as a separate file and have \include{packages} after the \documentclass thing. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Even though your question remained fully understandable, errors like this are always a bit of a red flag, because they suggest that the MWE was not actually tested exactly as posted. Worts case that means that the person asking the question is seeing something entirely different than those trying to answer. That's why I always recommend to test the example document in a new, empty folder before a post is submitted.

Comment: Off-topic: Do add periods to abbreviated given names in the `author` field. E.g., write `Struebig, Matthew J.` rather than just `Struebig, Matthew J`; You may ask, why? For sure, it doesn't make a difference if you always employ a bibliography style (such as `dcu`) which is programmed first and middle names to the first initial. However, it'll make a big difference if one day you have to use a different bibliography style, such as `plain` or `unsrtnat`, which does not truncate given names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that unlike APA style or Chicago style "Harvard style" does not refer to a specific bibliography and citation style with an official style guide. Instead Harvard style is usually broadly used to refer to author-year citations. As such there is no *actual* Harvard style.

Anyway, `dcu.bst` does not italicise "et al." by default and has no simple interface to change that on the fly, so we have to modify the `.bst` file directly.

The procedure to modify `dcu.bst` according to your wishes is as follows.

1. Locate `dcu.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich dcu.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/dcu.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine. See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf
3. Rename the file to `dcu-etal.bst`, say (the license of `dcu.bst` requires you to change the name if you modify the file)
4. Replace all occurrences of

   ```
   et~al.
   ```

   in the code with

   ```
   \harvardetal{}
   ```
5. Add a comment with your name, the current date and a short description of the changes to the top of the file.
6. Add the line `\newcommand*{\harvardetal}{\emph{et~al.}}` to your `.tex` document.
7. Use `\bibliographystyle{dcu-etal}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{dcu}` in your document.

As alternative for steps 1 to 5 you can obtain the patched version of the file at https://gist.github.com/moewew/941c01751b0a21106c08e6445d301756

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}

\usepackage[dcucite,abbr]{harvard}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\newcommand*{\harvardetal}{\emph{et~al.}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{oil-biodiv,  
  title     = {How will oil palm expansion affect biodiversity?},  
  author    = {Fitzherbert, Emily B. and Struebig, Matthew J.
               and Morel, Alexandra and Danielsen, Finn
               and Br{\"u}hl, Carsten A. and Donald, Paul F.
               and Phalan, Ben},  
  journal   = {Trends in ecology \& evolution},  
  volume    = {23},  
  number    = {10},  
  pages     = {538--545},  
  year      = {2008},  
  publisher = {Elsevier} 
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Vegetable oils are one of the most rapidly expanding sectors of agricultural expansion \cite{oil-biodiv}. 

\bibliographystyle{dcu-etal}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

now gives

[image: Fitzherbert *et al.*, 2008]

*edit:* Reflecting on how `harvard` handles `\harvardand` it seemed more appropriate to define a command `\harvardetal` that includes the typeset text directly. If one wanted to handle the following space with `\` more changes could be needed, so I opted for `{}` instead.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much for this. I will try this now and get back to you!!

Comment: Hi @moewe, this took alot longer than expected, but it worked!! I tried it before you made the correction, and it didn't work so was fumbling about for a bit - although I'm not sure if that was related. I also then deleted all the files that produced with the compilation (e.g. .aux .bbl .blg .fls etc) which has worked for me in the past when I have problems compiling. But yes after I compiled it again it worked!!! Thank you so, so much. I was this close to using MS Word to look for and manually change all the instances of et al., but that would have been a disaster. THANK YOU! :-)

Comment: @jumpingiraffes Glad that it works for you. Good luck with your project! Since we introduced the new command `\harvardetal` (`\harvardetalformat` in the old version) it is important that you have the `\newcommand` in the preamble of every document that uses `dcu-etal.bst`, otherwise LaTeX will complain about and undefined control sequence. Maybe it was that ...